# Selecting columns on same row as retrieved MAX

Tags: mysql

I have five columns in a table:

> id, a, b, c, d

My main query is:

```
SELECT MAX(a * (b/100)) AS result FROM mytable;
```

I'm trying to also display columns `c` and `d` that are relative to the row where `MAX` is pulled from. I'm finding it hard because the `MAX` query is using two columns rather than a single one. Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a where on subselect

```
select * 
from mytable 
cross join (

  SELECT MAX(a * (b/100)) AS result 
  FROM mytable
) t where (a * (b/100)) = t.result
```